# Is there a ready-to-use Session Hijacking protection API?

Tags: php, security

I have looked into many threads that discuss preventing Session hijacking & fixation but I feel that there are always details I'm missing out.

What I'm looking for is something with the same principle as what HTML Purifier does against XSS, but in this case against Session hijacking and fixation.

Is there an API or a PHP class made by anyone that covers everything that can be done to prevent Session Hijacking and Fixation?

Or is it better to do it on my own?

Thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: `What I'm looking for is something with the same principle as what HTML Purifier does against XSS` What, you want to escape your cookies? What principle is it, exactly?

Comment: Hi, I just meant that I wanted an API that is "ready to use", in the same way that HTML Purifier is.

Comment: Plenty of APIs are ready to use, but you'll need to specify what it needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

Session hijacking is when an attacker is able to read a users session cookie, and use that session cookie as their means to access your application. The only way to prevent an attacker from doing that is to use HTTPS for everything. There is no API to use, because there isn't anything the application can do otherwise to prevent someone from stealing the session cookie if they can set up man in the middle situations.

Comment: Httponly cookies in case of XSS wouldn't hurt, though.

Comment: @arxanas: Well, sure. But XSS is not session hijacking. XSS achieves exploits by tricking the client into doing something bad, which may include sending session cookies to an attacker. But that's not what someone is typically talking about when they are speaking about "session hijacking."

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're searching a solution which is equal to `session.cookie_httponly` set to 1.

And maybe `session.use_only_cookies` in addition (but not instead!).

In this case your session's cookie will be always hidden from JS.

*Update:* read Billy ONeal answer and comment on HTTPS

*Was:* HTTPS as mentioned by Billy ONeal is rather an extra thing, then the base one with this problem. Man-in-middle is an "expensive" kind of attack, so if you have some data to protect from visitor's ISP, then your website is already behind HTTPS I think. While the stolen session is a common problem.

Comment: Man in the middle is not an "expensive" attack -- anyone on the same network segment can carry it out easily. If you're not on the same network segment it's a bit more difficult; but it by no means requires the attacker "be the ISP." The session key is the user's identity, and security requires protecting it as such.

Comment: @BillyONeal I agree, there was a generalization in my answer. With arguable point.

Answer (score -3):

It is always better to make one yourself. It might be harder and in the end not do much, but frameworks and APIs are accessible from those guys who will make the high-jacking.

Try encrypting your sessions and working that way. Security requires drastic changes to the architecture of a platform and consequently of its database

Comment: -1: `It is always better to make one yourself`... One should not roll their own encryption. Almost invariably, people are bad at it. Open-source frameworks are tested better and reviewed by more people.